# Browsers Autofill feature doesnt trigger any JS events

Tags: javascript, html, browser, autofill, dom-events

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="username" value="Username">
<div style="position:relative">
<span style="position:absolute;top:0;" id="passwordTxt">Password</span>
<input style="position:absolute;top:0;visibility:visible;" 
type="password" id="password" value="">
</div>
</form>

var obj=document.getElementById("password")
obj.addEventListener( "change", change(0) , false );
obj.addEventListener( "input", change(0) , false );
obj.addEventListener( "focus", change(0) , false );
obj.addEventListener( "blur", change(1) , false );

function change(action){
return function (){ 
var txt = document.getElementById("passwordTxt")
var pass= document.getElementById("password")
if(action){
if(pass.value =="")
txt.style.visibility="visible";
}
else txt.style.visibility="hidden";
}
}
```

The presence of `type="password"` will enable the browser to prompt for the `remember password` feature. If the user name is already existing ,drop down pop's up with cached username and if its `password` exist - it gets populated by the browser - quite handy. but,that feature doesnt trigger any JS events!!. I want the `span` to be hidden if password or any value is entered into that password textbox, but the browsers feature is letting a small bug creep up.

Any help is appreciated.( Am not working with jQuery ,so a plain JS workaround/solution is what would help me)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to overshadow the text box with title Password if it is empty. The simple solution I could think of is to hook on to page load and see if the text is available.

The better approach is to use existing and tested frameworks. You can find what you are looking for in Bootstrap. Goto http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms and look at inline forms example

Comment: hook on to page load and check for text availablity??.. can you elaborate on that??.. and,yes - what's happening in inline forms is what i'm trying to achieve ,unfortunately am having a tuff time at it..

Comment: Why not use bootstrap itself? as from your code you are not targetting IE anyways?

Comment: well,its just a sample code.. and i wanted it to be cross-broser,and boot strap - uses HTML5 , which is again - not compatible for older browsers.

Comment: Try document.addEventListener( "load", change(1) , false ); (Note Older version of IE don't support addEventListener)